# Perseguição de downvoter

Tags: suporte

Existe alguma ação para quando somos "perseguidos"? rs

[image]

---

UPDATE:

Conforme informaram, foram estornados os pontos:

[image]

Comment: O sistema cuidará disso sozinho e reverterá os votos; isso acontece ao fechamento do dia, se não me engano. Caso não aconteça, você pode relatar aos moderadores que eles analisarão a situação, tal como fez aqui, basicamente.

Comment: Tem um outro usuário que reclama disso, o @Articuno. E segundo ele, a moderação não fez nada...

Comment: Não é nem pelos pontos... é porque esse tipo de usuário, na minha opinião, não serve para uma comunidade. É o tipo de pessoa birrenta, não aceita opiniões, não sabe reconhecer erros, etc. Eu não achei quem é, porque ou veio pela "revisão" ou algum comentário, e tive muito poucos hoje. Mas deve ser um "sabe tudo" birrento só... Pra mim isso seria atitude pra ban... Fazer o que... rs

Comment: Eu até gostaria que isto fosse levado mais a sério, porque eu estou sempre entre os 3 que mais levam negativos por vingança. Neste momento tem um que adora negativar as perguntas que eu coloco recompensa. Eu gasto reputação com ou outros e o que eu ganho é ódio.

Comment: Então... e esse é o típico cara que mais precisa daqui, porque não aceita estar errado, não aceita opinião sobre suas respostas, o que atrasa o aprendizado e faz ficar dependente de fóruns e comunidades...

Comment: Eu tb to sofrendo so q no meu caso, o cara nao votou seguidamente, esse sistema da SE é tao ridiculo que qualquer um manipula. Eu nao terei meus votos devolvidos e o imbecil continuará impune. Felizmente no seu caso o sistema reverterá.

Comment: Nossa e acredito ser simples fazer algo que verifique isso né...

Comment: @Maniero Você também tem perseguição desse gênero ? Essa não estava eu a espera! E não ha nada que possa fazer, tendo em conta que é moderador ? (Felizmente ainda não faço parte dos perseguidos!)

Comment: No todo eu sou o mais perseguido do site. Eu posso fazer algo, mas aí vão dizer que estou usando o poder de moderador em proveito próprio, então deveria ser feito por outros moderadores. Mas nem é tão simples, a maior parte dos casos precisa de verificação individual de votação que só os CMs podem fazer. Mesmo estando óbvio, só com essa verificação para ter 100% de certeza. E não há muito interesse em fazer isto. Tem vários casos no passado que não eram resolvidos e agora sequer temos um CM dedicado (o que nem dá pra dizer que piorou).

Comment: Até quando o próprio sistema me prejudicou não consegui que algo fosse feito. Então o que dá para fazer é ficar desmotivado mesmo. Eu ando com menos tempo, mas eu poderia fazer um esforço, mas não tenho interesse em fazer esforço por algo que não me valoriza. Tem coisas que eu ia fazer que seria bom pra comunidade como um todo, que atende aos interesses da SE, mas por que eu vou gastar meu tempo nisso se eles não gastam tempo em melhorar o sistema ou verificar manualmente esses casos mais difíceis? Por que não agem como o discurso e mostrem o problema em vez de punir?

Comment: Sim, porque eles falam que é melhor editar, ajudar a pessoa melhorar, apontar o problema em vez de fechar ou negativar. Mas não melhoram a ferramenta para facilitar isso, não mudam o sistema para que ele te mostre que tem algo errado (o sistema tenta esconder que você foi "punido" por algo possivelmente errado que você fez), e o sistema e os CMs acabam desincentivando que você fale algo abertamente porque se isso te gerar perseguição o problema é seu. Então tem muita coisa errada, e não mudam. Eles sabem disto tudo, não é novidade.

Comment: Eu, e não sou o único, claro, sofro muito mais a perseguição branca do que a óbvia. A branca causa muito mais problema que a óbvia, que pune muito mais e é mais difícil você afirmar algo, mas algumas são tão contundentes que deveria ter algo para resolver. Eu não gosto de falar misso porque ensina coisa errada, mas vou falar. Para quem não sabe o que é a perseguição branca, é não votar em certas pessoas. Quando você deixa de votar você pune 5X mais que um negativo porque ele deixa de dar 10 pontos merecidos e o negativo só tira 2. Mas o ponto eu nem ligo, eu ligo para o conteúdo ñ reconhecido.

Comment: Mais ainda, o sujeito muitas vezes vota em outra resposta para destacá-la. Porque tem o problema do "maria vai com as outras" e ocorre até com usuários que deveria ser insuspeitos, mas esse é um problema bem mais difícil de resolver (as pessoas votam no que está aceito ou bem votado, deixando de lado as demais respostas, mesmo que elas sejam melhores, e pior, quando a votada está errada, ela perpetua o erro, tem solução, pelo menos parcial, mas a SE não quer certamente terá várias desculpas para não fazê-lo).

Comment: Eu sempre percebi perseguição branca, a não ser nos casos muito leves. Agora como moderador eu posso ter certeza, e até mesmo dos casos leves. E vou confessar que eu faço algo errado, mas não não para fazer diferente, é uma questão de se proteger da perseguição que não é resolvida. Eu não voto em quem não vota em mim de propósito e a pessoa é bastante prejudicada também. Muitas vezes ela sabe disso, mas o ódio dela é tão grande que ela não liga, ela quer prejudicar, não importa o preço que pague.

Comment: Vou dar um exemplo. Tem um usuário que é muito forte em tag onde eu sou forte. Essa pessoa deu mais de 10 negativos em mim, ele é o 2o. ou 3o. maior negativador meu, ele deu pouco mais que isso de positivos em mim, a maioria antes de começar a perseguição, e os que que deu depois ele fezes questão de falar publicamente que estava votando, para parecer que ele faz a coisa certa. Ele vota muito mais em outros usuários que respondem bem mais do que eu nessa tag, e claramente essa pessoas não são tão fortes nesta tag ainda. É caso claro de seletividade de votos. Ele tem capacidade de avaliar...

Comment: ...meus posts, frequenta as perguntas da tag, muitas vezes responde junto, mas não voto em coisa minha. E é uma pessoa considerada na comunidade. Não tem como eu não ter atitude igual. Tem outro caso na mesma tag, mesmas condições, a diferença que é uma pessoa que a comunidade tem problemas, essa pessoa não votou positivo em mim nada ou quase nada (se a pessoa dá 1 voto eu não tenho como saber porque o sistema revelaria quem votou onde e a SE não quer que moderadores saibam disso, o que é outro erro. Ou confia no moderador ou não confia, ou dá tudo o que ele precisa, ou não dá tanto).

Comment: Tem vários outros casos. Na verdade muita gente faz isso, porque pela participação que eu tenho no site, olhando tag por tag, no que cada pessoa participa, a maioria das pessoas deveriam votar mais em mim do que votam. Isso não é exclusivo comigo, mas o meu caso eu sei melhor, por óbvio. Não tem mais do que uns 10 usuários que votam em mim em proporção adequada ao que votam em outras pessoas. Tenho os fãs tb, que votam muito em mim, entre esses "10", mas a maioria dentro de normalidade. Isto provavelmente não aconteceria se o sistema e a comunidade fosses mais justos.

Comment: Mesmo os usuários que não posso falar que me perseguem, posso dizer que tem alguns que tem uma tendenciosidade de votar menos em mim do que deveria, pelo padrão de votos dela, isso vale pra imensa maioria das pessoas que votam (os que não votam, ou só votam no que ele perguntou eu até desconsidero). Na verdade tem a perseguição branca geral. Tem usuário importante no site, e não são tão poucos assim, vários com 5 dígitos de rep, que participam muito, então não podem dizer que não tem tempo de avaliar, que não vota em quase nada. Tem gente que até se for olhar eu sou quem ele mais vota, mas...

Comment: são apenas 10, 20 votos. A maioria dos usuários que votam bem tem centenas de votos em mim, eu estou chegando aos 5000 posts. Salvo um ou outro as pessoas não votam nem em 10% do que eu respondi. Se for ver, elas votam em muito mais de 10% do que outras pessoas postam, alguns casos é normal, outros nem tanto. E olhe que estou analisando por tag, porque é óbvio que uma pessoa que posta muito em R ou mesmo Ruby terá uma proporção maior de votos do que em mim se essa pessoa que vota tb é fã dessas tecnologias, ela tem motivos para votar menos em mim.

Comment: Então tem coisas erradas no padrão de votação que eu recebo para prejudicar ou beneficiar, mas só porque o sistema é ruim. E tem outra coisa que eu faço e não me orgulho porque outras pessoas fazem também, que é não votar em outra resposta que concorre com a minha em um pergunta. Eu até voto, quando a pessoa costuma votar em outra também. Quando eu vejo que a pessoa deixa de votar pra ficar melhor na sua, eu tendo a fazer o mesmo com essa pessoa. O que alimenta um círculo vicioso, mas como a SE não tem uma solução para isto, ele acaba sendo necessário.

Comment: Teve época que havia até o incentivo explícito da SE para agir assim. Eu adoraria dar o exemplo e da a outra face, mas não sou cristo e não vai me ajudar em nada, nem a comunidade porque ninguém verá o exemplo sendo dado. Eu até dou a outra face em casos leves. Então todas essas atitudes são prejudiciais, mas seria um absurdo a SE querer que as pessoas parem de se proteger se ela não faz (quase) nada para proteger as pessoas. Muita coisa precisa ser repensada. Eu quero ver se a SE começar punir pessoas porque elas não usam um artigo de gênero indefinido quando se expressa(e é só um exemplo)...

Comment: ... e não punir que causa mal de fato, distúrbio na comunidade com votações erráticas. Vira coisa tipo ecologista ou religioso fundamentalista (alguns apenas, claro), sabe o cara que mata uma pessoa pra salvar a plantinha, ou mata uma pessoa pra salvar um monte de célula se formando, ou mesmo outros tipos que destroem um pessoa porque ela deu uma leve deslizada em algum ponto que não causou prejuízo de fato pra ninguém, e que geralmente são as pessoas que defendem menos ou zero punição para criminosos óbvios.

Comment: Desculpa o desabafo :) Mas essas coisas vão se acumulando, e você não vê ninguém querendo resolver. Eu ainda tento fazer o meu melhor que não seja prejudicial pra mim, ainda sou um moderador de grande atividade, ajudo a comunidade em muito, mas menos do que antes, porque é difícil se manter motivado igual quando é desvalorizado. Duvido que alguém em sã consciência poderia me recriminar por não ser a maior perfeição. E note que eu entendo que dou motivos pras perseguições (ma te mcasos que é só porque tento fazer o melhor), hoje muito menos, mas ainda assim deveria ser resolvido de outra forma.

Comment: Sim não é fácil, o sistema tem umas quantas falhas de facto. E eu percebo os seus pontos de vista e acho que ninguém poderia julga-lo nesse sentido. Acho que a comunidade como um todo acaba por votar pouco, incluindo usuários de reputação elevada. Eu esforço-me por votar bastante em conteúdo de qualidade e imparcialmente, mas somos todos humanos, por isso é normal de por vezes derraparmos um pouco.

Comment: É um pouco desmotivante ouvir isso de vocês, usuários antigos com grande reputação. Eu não sei como funciona o SO/SE, mas achei que moderadores tinham muito mais "poderes" na ferramenta. Isso deixa uma imagem de "se está funcionando, melhor não mexer", o que afeta em partes a "evolução" da ferramenta.

Comment: @RBZ pense pelo lado positivo: você ganhou um fã! Parabéns pelo trabalho, não é todo mundo que consegue xD E se considere batizado na comunidade, huehuehue

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado pior, o cara não tem nem parâmetro pra perseguição! Perseguir iniciante! kkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: Uma dúvida... esse estorno dos meus pontos, também estorna para o quem os deu ?

Comment: @Isac o triste e não ver melhoras. Eu sou quem mais votou até agora, mas já votei mais do que voto agora. Se alguém acha que merece mais votos vindos de mim porque percebe que não voto em certas coisas, deveria fazer o mesmo. Claro eu erro também, não só na avaliação objetivo, mas também por falhar emocionais, não sou um robozinho. E já fiz até algo que posso considerar falhar de caráter, pra fazer uma autocrítica, mas me arrependi e foi bem pouco. Só não considero atitudes defensivas como um problema grave, caso contrário eu não faria. Cada um que julgue como quiser.

Comment: @RBZ Eu acho que a comunidade deveria ter quase os mesmo poderes que o moderadores, exceto coisas que podem violar privacidade, definitivas (e muitas que hoje são, não deveriam ser) e coisas mais graves. Claro que a comunidade deveria ter que ter um certo consenso para evitar decisões equivocadas, em alguns casos precisa mais critério, mas seleção de quem tem poder de fogo, mas todos que se mostrem capazes deveriam poder participar da moderação. E os mods deveriam ter + poder pra fazer algumas coisas que só CMs fazem, até porque eles  não parecem ter tempo para fazer o que precisa.Vc tá bem :)

Comment: Quem persegue não tem parâmetro algum E estorna pra ele também, o que dá pra discutir se não deveria ser o contrário. O sistema incentiva muito coisas erradas. Ele é bom, e não espero ser perfeito, mas você vai vendo erros demais e nada é feito. E gastam energia discutindo coisas que não causam problema e são polêmicas demais para ter alguma ação efetiva.

Comment: @Maniero É verdade,a sua quantidade de votos é estonteante! :D. Acho que só isso já é motivo de orgulho pois demonstra que se esforça por esta comunidade. Afinal de contas é preciso tempo e dedicação para votar, pois é necessário ser critico e analisar as publicações uma a uma. E é como tinha dito, no final do dia somos humanos, por isso é normal sermos influenciados até certo ponto sobre ações de terceiros em nós próprios. E provavelmente você será dos que menos se deixa afetar, porque tem muita gente que rapidamente se revolta e vira bixo contra tudo e todos!

Comment: @RBZ "_Uma dúvida... esse estorno dos meus pontos, também estorna para o quem os deu ?_"... sim.

Comment: @Maniero "_Neste momento tem um que adora negativar as perguntas que eu coloco recompensa._"... vou colocar minha cara a tapa: sou eu mesmo rs...eu voto não por ódio, vingança ou qualquer desses sentimentos espúrios. Eu voto por  considerar que a pergunta tem falhas ou outro motivo que me leva a votar assim, como tb voto positivo, como já fiz várias vezes. Mas não tem nada de ódio nem vingança, é questão de opinião mesmo, equivocada ou não, é opinião. Assim como recebo alguns -1 sem entender direito o motivo, mas é a vida. Como diz o ditado: não é possível agradar a gregos e troianos.

Comment: @dvd Não é, como moderador eu sei quem é, nós temos acesso à votações, sabemos quem vota dentro de um padrão tendencioso. Você pode ter dado um ou outro negativo, mas não como clara perseguição. Fui ver agora, até existe uma anomalia nos seus votos, mas nada que caracterize clara fraude, vingança, nada dessas coisas, pelo menos não neste momento. Existe anomalia em muita gente, até comigo :) O contrário tb é verdadeiro, não há indícios de perseguição em você e é o máximo que posso dizer sem dizer o que é sigiloso :)

Comment: Lá no SO em inglês tem um certo usuário que não vou mencionar, mas ele quer ser o "dono" de uma *tag*, quer ser o primeiro a responder, quando respondem antes, qq mínimo problema ele comenta ou "magicamente" aparecem negativos. Simplesmente parei de ver essa *tag*. Quem perde é a comunidade infelizmente

Comment: @RicardoPontual Acho que deveria mencionar o usuário pra gente ver (e se divertir um pouco :D) já que é de outro site da rede. Seria bem legal! rss

Comment: Da mesma forma que existe _cereal downvoter_, existe também o _serial upvoter_... vez em quando eu começo a receber um monte de upvote em várias respostas minhas! (não estou reclamando rsrs)...

Comment: O usuário é **lankymart**  ele adora as perguntas da tag `asp-classic`, vocês vão ver que tem muita coisa negativada nessa tag, entre perguntas e respostas. Ele tem ótimas respostas, a pena são algumas atitudes por lá....

Comment: Sim, às vezes aparece um *serial upvoter*, desse ninguém reclama :)